# SUPEE-6285 errors

Tags: error, security, patches, supee-6285

I am new to installing patches but first attempt has failed.  Could anyone tell me what I could have done wrong?

```
root@server1 [/home/mtlengin/public_html]# sh PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v2-2015-07-08-08-07-43.sh
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

patching file app/Mage.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 813 (offset -1 lines).
patching file app/code/community/Phoenix/Moneybookers/controllers/MoneybookersController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/AjaxController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Category/WidgetController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/DatafeedsController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/ReviewController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/WidgetController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/Block/WidgetController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/Page/WidgetController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/PageController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/WysiwygController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Customer/System/Config/ValidatevatController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/JsonController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/NotificationController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/CustomerController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/ProductController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/ReviewController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/SalesController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/ShopcartController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/TagController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/ReportController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Rss/CatalogController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Rss/OrderController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Billing/AgreementController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/View/GiftmessageController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Recurring/ProfileController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/TransactionsController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/Config/System/StorageController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/TagController.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 346 (offset 1 line).
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Tax/RateController.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 455 (offset -11 lines).
can't find file to patch at input line 571
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/TaxController.php app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/TaxController.php
|index b5fcba2..c52dd71 100644
|--- app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/TaxController.php
|+++ app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/TaxController.php
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Api2/controllers/Adminhtml/Api2/AttributeController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/controllers/Adminhtml/Bundle/SelectionController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/controllers/Adminhtml/RefreshController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Centinel/controllers/Adminhtml/Centinel/IndexController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/MultishippingController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Connect/controllers/Adminhtml/Extension/LocalController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Abstract.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 89 with fuzz 2 (offset -6 lines).
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Oauth/controllers/Adminhtml/Oauth/AuthorizeController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Paygate/controllers/Adminhtml/Paygate/Authorizenet/PaymentController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/controllers/Adminhtml/Paypal/ReportsController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Rss/controllers/CatalogController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Rss/controllers/OrderController.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 77 (offset 2 lines).
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Widget/Block/Adminhtml/Widget/Chooser.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Widget/controllers/Adminhtml/WidgetController.php
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 97 (offset -1 lines).
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/noItems.phtml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 31 with fuzz 1.
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/failure.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/rss/order/details.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/wishlist/email/rss.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/default/modern/template/checkout/cart.phtml
can't find file to patch at input line 907
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml
|index 7bceece..88753c3 100644
|--- app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml
|+++ app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
patching file downloader/Maged/.htaccess
patching file downloader/Maged/Controller.php
Hunk #4 succeeded at 451 (offset -5 lines).
Hunk #5 FAILED at 1139.
1 out of 5 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file downloader/Maged/Controller.php.rej
patching file downloader/Maged/Model/Session.php
Hunk #2 succeeded at 228 with fuzz 2 (offset -13 lines).
patching file downloader/lib/.htaccess
patching file downloader/template/connect/packages.phtml
Hunk #3 succeeded at 176 (offset -1 lines).
patching file downloader/template/connect/packages_prepare.phtml
Hunk #1 FAILED at 33.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file downloader/template/connect/packages_prepare.phtml.rej
patching file downloader/template/login.phtml
patching file downloader/template/settings.phtml
patching file errors/processor.php
```

Answer (score 1):

Some reasons this would happen:

- You've downloaded the wrong version of the patch for your install
- Core Magento files have been modified
- You are patching an unsupported Magento version

Can you confirm which one you downloaded?  And what version of Magento are you currently running?

Answer (score 0):

You can at any stage use the -R option with the patch command to rollback/revert and try again after that.  Maybe that helps.